# Link server error Invalid use of schema or catalog for OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "LINK71"

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a `Link Server` using this:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LINK71', @srvproduct=N'serverInstance', @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=N'serverInstance', @catalog=N'mydb'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'LINK71',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'myuname',@rmtpassword='mypassword'

GO
```

It is created successfully but my problem is it returns an error like above when i started to run the link server like:

```
SELECT top 1 [Col1]
      ,[Col2]
      ,[Col3]
  FROM [LINK71].[DB].[dbo].[Tbl_sample]
GO
```

What did i missed up?

Iv'e also tried to search some post but no luck.

**Here's some additional details:**

This is the Image from link Server that tables has no column from right area:

[image]

And this is the image from normal Server with an option from the right area the addition sign to expand but link server has nothing:

[image]

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From BOL: [sp_addlinkedserver (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql)

> [ @catalog= ] 'catalog' Is the catalog to be used when a connection is
>   made to the OLE DB provider. catalog is sysname, with a default of
>   NULL. catalog is passed as the DBPROP_INIT_CATALOG property to
>   initialize the OLE DB provider. When the linked server is defined
>   against an instance of SQL Server, catalog refers to the default
>   database to which the linked server is mapped.

So or you don't use @catalog at all when define your linked server
(doing so you can refer any db from the linked server later) and then you can use your syntax like

```
[LINK71].[DB].[dbo].[Tbl_sample]
```

Or you use @catalog in linked server definition as you did, but then you cannot use other db that are not mydb (from your @catalog=N'mydb')

Comment: I mean if you want to reference DB database on your linked server, you shouldn't use @ catalog =N 'mydb' in linked server definition, use just EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @ server = N'LINK71', @ srvproduct=N'serverInstance', @ provider=N'SQLNCLI', @ datasrc=N'serverInstance' without parameter @ catalog

Comment: The problem is, i can see all the tables from the link server but there's is no column created and don't have any option to expand the tables.. only just tables names viewed.

Comment: if you use the catalog parameter, you cannot use database name later when you refer linked server, i.e. [LINK71].[dbo].[Tbl_sample], without [db], db = myDB if you used the catalog parameter

Comment: >>>there's is no column created and don't have any option to expand the tables<<< this is normal

Comment: if that is a normal as  you've said.. I don't even know why there's no any column result when i try to run the query like "SELECT [col1]
      ,[col2]
      ,[col3]
  FROM [LINK71].[mydb].[dbo].[Tbl_sample]
GO
" instead it returns me an error.

Comment: What permissions has myuname on that server in that db?

Comment: Maybe my permission is not enough to do it? in my PC i am using sa username. . but in the server which is i created the link server.. i think it is reader only.. i don't have enough access to that server. but when i try to connect it in a normal connection using engine. I can search all the records using that myuname.

Comment: you can check your permissions at database level running this: select *
from openquery ([LINK71], 'select * from MYDB.sys.fn_my_permissions(null, ''database'')')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144919/discussion-between-redzsol-and-sepupic).

Comment: it has only CONNECT AND SELECT for myuname

Comment: Thanks to you @sepupic.. i am just a new here in SQL. thanks for understanding.. upvoted your post.

Comment: Even i change DB to mydb it show me the same error.

Comment: Re-create your linked server without specifying any catalog

Comment: You are db_datareader on that server in that database, so you only can select the data

Comment: yes its true.. Meaning don't have the right to use link server?

Comment: Yes you can, you can read all the user tables from that db on linked server. The server is set up correclty, otherwise you could not even see the tables. Try this: right mouse click on the table you are iterested in, Script Table as, Select to, New Query Window. This should produce the code that gives no error

Comment: I did a google search on this error because it's very strange situation, the server is set up correctly, your syntax is also correct and you have all the necessary permissions, so it can be smth else. I found this one: check the option "Level Zero Only" in Server Objects/Linked Server/Providers/SQLNCLI, this mus be unchecked

Comment: I did this checked and unchecked but it give me same error.

Comment: Did you try to script the select statement using Management Studio: right mouse click on the table you are iterested in, Script Table as, Select to, New Query Window?

Comment: What is your server version and propertiy of what Provider did you change?

Comment: SQL Server 12.0 and my PC SQL Server 10.0

Comment: So your Provider is SQLNCLI10? You can try to install SQLNCLI11 on your pc and create another linked server using SQLNCLI11

Comment: It's good idea, it seems like yesterday i think about it.. to install same even SQL Server 12.0 just to compare the result. thanks.. I'll it